# How do I retrieve the last good build with depth 2 with the Python JenkinsAPI

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-api

I'm trying to retrieve the build data for a specific build with depth 2 but the default is always 1

```
J = Jenkins(host,user,password)
job = J.get_job(job_name)
build_number = job.get_last_good_build()
```

It's not mentioned in the documentation, only how to create build object with depth 2.

How do I get it with depth 2 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "depth 2"? Is it inside a _Folder_? Then you can use the method twice like this: `job = J.get_job('FOLDERNAME').get_job('JOBNAME')`.

Comment: The data at depth=2 is what i need for the build. Since the fingerprints I require from build._data is at that level

Comment: I am sorry, but it's still not clear to me. Is the job you are looking for inside a folder or do you want to get the fingerprint of a build?

Comment: The fingerprint of a build at depth 2

Comment: Please define "depth".

Comment: http:/my-jenkins/job/jobName/job/jobsName/653/api/json?pretty=true&depth=2

When specified as above in the json API request

Comment: In the latest version of the Jenkins API for Python there is the method [`get_job_info`](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.get_job_info). It has the input argument `depth`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for thanks. Missed that in the documentation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of the Jenkins API for Python there is the method get_job_info. It has the input argument depth.

By the user [Sven Krüger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7545157/sven-kr%C3%BCger)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the API has it by default. Best thing I can think of is to get a list of all jobs, and query each on for a success, if your job fails often you could start with the last_good_build and work your way down/

I don't know Python that well, but I wrote a very bad script in GO to get all successful builds, you'd just have to add logic to stop at depth 2:

You would have to do something like:

```
    builds, err := jenkins.GetAllBuildIds(jobName)
    var count int64
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, build := range builds {
        buildID := build.Number
        data, err := jenkins.GetBuild(jobName, buildID)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        if "SUCCESS" == data.GetResult() {
            <LOGIC>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use foward slash `/` to separate nested jobs. It will work for directories and Organization plugins, such as Bitbucket Team Project.

```
job = J.get_job("{}/{}".format(organization, job_name))
```